# put an div with input at bottom in bootstrap col

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I made a chat app in React and I have a little problem with styling UI. For the project I use bootstrap. I use a row with two columns; One it's for users in the room, and the other it's for the chat panels.
Below is its JSX code:

```
<div className="room">
      <div className="row no-gutters">
        <div className="col-md-4 border-right">
          <div className="settings-tray">
            <div className="text">
              <h6>Room nr {id}</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
          {users.map((u, i) => (
            <>
              <div key={i} className="friend-drawer friend-drawer--onhover">
                <div className="text">
                  <h6>{u}</h6>
                </div>
              </div>
              <hr />
            </>
          ))}
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-8 d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
          <div className="settings-tray">
            <div className="friend-drawer no-gutters friend-drawer--grey">
              <div className="text">
                <h6>{room?.game}</h6>
              </div>
              <span className="settings-tray--right">
                <i className="material-icons">cached</i>
                <i className="material-icons">message</i>
                <i className="material-icons">menu</i>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div
            className="chat-panel"
            style={{ height: "100%", overflow: "scroll" }}
          >
            {messages.map((message, i) => (
              <div key={i} className="row no-gutters">
                <div
                  className={`col-md-3 ${
                    context.user.displayName === message.displayName &&
                    "offset-md-9"
                  }`}
                >
                  <div
                    className={`chat-bubble chat-bubble--${
                      context.user.displayName === message.displayName
                        ? "right"
                        : "left"
                    }`}
                  >
                    <p className="text-muted">{message.displayName}</p>
                    {message.msg}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
            <div className="row align-items-end">
              <div className="col-12">
                <div className="chat-box-tray">
                  <i className="material-icons">sentiment_very_satisfied</i>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Type your message here..."
                    onChange={(e) => setMsg(e.target.value)}
                  />
                  <i className="material-icons">mic</i>
                  <i onClick={send} className="material-icons">
                    send
                  </i>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

the problem's the text input it's not at the bottom. How to set the text input with send and mic buttons at the bottom of the page. I put an image with the UI.
Thanks[image: ui]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the problem here. Could you please add a definition of what is a "text input"? Is it the text sentiment_very_satisfied? If so, maybe simply add a html block tag (ex: div) around the tag elements:

```
 <div className="chat-box-tray">
  <div>
   <i className="material-icons">sentiment_very_satisfied</i>
  </div>
  <input
    type="text"
    placeholder="Type your message here..."
    onChange={(e) => setMsg(e.target.value)}
  />
  <div>
   <i className="material-icons">mic</i>
   <i onClick={send} className="material-icons">
    send
   </i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the "text input" is the div with "chat-box-tray" class